set value for conditional initializer property in class model
given below was my model:
public class RelationContentTypeObject
{
    [JsonProperty("$id")]
    private string IdField { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$ref")]
    private string RefField { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Id  => IdField ?? RefField;
    }

from this i want to directly set value for Id property and this is for xunit testing
i am trying to access Id property directly

The Id property is a getter, getter properties cannot be assigned to, as they return value only. You should think of it just like a method string GetId(). It would not make sense to do seomthing like myObj.GetId() = someId; , would it?
But, looking at the getter, it looks first for IdField property and returns it if it's not null. So if you want to set some non-null value to the property, you need to assign this value to IdField.
On the other hand, if you want null, you must to assign null to IdField and RefField (or leave them empty).
For example
RelationContentTypeObject o1 = new();

o1.IdField = "some id"; // here you will have Id getter filled

RelationContentTypeObject o2 = new();
// Here o2.Id will be null, as we left IdField and RefField empty.
// Or you could do o2.IdField = o2.RefField = null;

